# got property undefined when fetching data in ajax using vue.js

Tags: javascript, alert, vue.js

I have got a undefined when I alert the param fetching from ajax using vue.js, here is my code.

test.json return:

```
[
  {isActive: false,name: test}
]
```

js:

```
new Vue({
el: '#viewport',
data: {

    test_data: []
},
mounted: function () {
    this.fetchTestData();
},
methods: {
    fetchTestData: function () {
        $.get(test.json, function (data) {

            this.test_data = data;
            alert(this.test_data.isActive);
        });

    }
}
});
```

I am beginner of vue.js, hope have a reply, thanks.

Comment: test_data is an array. Try `this.test_data[0].active`

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks for reply, but also undefined.

Comment: Can you check what `data` logs. If its string, you might need to parse it to object using `JSON.parse`

Comment: you means this?  this.test_data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Yup. If you are sending data as string, you will need to convert in to object

Comment: um..when I alert the data, it will show the json to me, I also guess that it is a string, but when I JSON.parse(data), javascript error, any idea?

Comment: @Winston What is the JS error you are getting on parse?

Comment: hi surabh, it is  JavaScript runtime error: 'isActive' is undefined

Comment: I change it to :
                var wholeData = JSON.parse(data);
                this.test_data= wholeData;
Then JS error: JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fetching this data from that `test.json` file,
first it need to be like that because that's not validate json:

```
[
  {
    "isActive": false,
    "name": "test"
    }
]
```

and you need to use `bind` because `this` not referring to the Vue instance

```
    fetchTestData: function () {
        $.get('test.json', function (data) {
            this.test_data = data;
            alert(this.test_data[0].isActive);
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

and accessing the data like that `this.test_data[0].isActive` because it's an array

Comment: exactly the [0] because the array.
or you can give `this.test_data = data[0]` and `alert(this.test_data.isActive);`

Comment: I have follow the above step, alert this.test_data display correct data, but alert this.test_data.isActive display undefined.

Comment: @Winston notice the `[0]` because it's an array, did you try that?